# my python script with subprocess doesn't work when run as systemctl service

Tags: python, c, subprocess

complete noob here, so please bear with me.

i have a python script that runs a subprocess when i press a button of a remote control. The subprocess is a small C program that measures the sample rate of an audio signal and passes the value to the python script as binary.

Once the python script gets the value, i need to multiply it by 10 and continue doing other stuff.

the relevant part of the python code is this:

```
def oled_stringSR():

    a = subprocess.run("gcc freq_count_2.c -lpigpio -lrt -o out1;./out1", capture_output = True, shell = True)
    d = 10*int(a.stdout)
    if d < 40001:
        sample_rate = 32
    elif 40000 < d < 46001:
        sample_rate = 44.1
```

etc etc...

when i run the complete script from terminal with sudo, everything works as intended. However, when i run it as a systemctl service and i trigger that part of the script with the remote control, it stops working and journalctl registers the following:

```
May 17 23:19:00 raspcamilla oled[1076]: Traceback (most recent call last):
May 17 23:19:00 raspcamilla oled[1076]:   File "/home/marcosch/remote.py", line 2231, in <module>
May 17 23:19:00 raspcamilla oled[1076]:     main()
May 17 23:19:00 raspcamilla oled[1076]:   File "/home/marcosch/remote.py", line 1267, in main
May 17 23:19:00 raspcamilla oled[1076]:     oled_stringSR()
May 17 23:19:00 raspcamilla oled[1076]:   File "/home/marcosch/remote.py", line 2084, in oled_stringSR
May 17 23:19:00 raspcamilla oled[1076]:     d = 10*int(a.stdout)
May 17 23:19:00 raspcamilla oled[1076]: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b''
```

looks like the C program is not running or outputting nothing.
I get exactly the same error when i run the python script from terminal without sudo, so i suspect it is the second option. I read around that systemctl services run always from root... any idea what is going on here?

as additional info:
all this is in Ubuntu server 22.04 running on a raspberry pi.

any help, clue or comment will be very much appreciated, thanks!

after reading other similar (probable not that similar) issues and solutions, i tried to modify the service file, without success. My current service looks like this:

```
[Unit]
After=syslog.target
StartLimitIntervalSec=10
StartLimitBurst=10

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=python3 /home/marcosch/remote.py
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
StandardOutput=journal
StandardError=journal
SyslogIdentifier=oled
User=root
Group=root

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

Comment: You didn't get an exception, so the program ran. `b''` means that stdout was empty. So, what do `a.returncode` and `a.stderr` have in them? You are using a relative path to `freq_count_2.c` so its most likely the case that your Current Working Directory is in a different place than you think.

Comment: Have you tied to change the `User=root`?  Otherwise that 'b' says that the input may be a bytes object. You can try to put a debug trace on the line after the subprocess run to examine the output using `from pdb import set_trace; set_trace()` in order to interactively examine the `a.returncode` and `a.stderr` as suggested by tdelaney.  Also you can set the working directory for systemd with `WorkingDirectory=` in the `[Service]` block

Comment: Try changing `freq_count_2.c` to `~/freq_count_2.c` to specify the full path to your source file.

Comment: @Barmar - good point except it assumes there is a home directory for the user and that the .c file is in that directory. I think that `cwd="/path/to/parent/directory"` in the `subprocess.run` call would work. But there may still be a problem with that directory being writable by the running process.

Comment: guys, thank you all for your answers, really! sorry for the late reply, i have been trying all  the suggestions that i could. The one that worked is to add the WorkingDirectory= my user directory in the service document. Thanks all and most specially VoMWooDSoN. I think i understand the issue (50%) but would never get there without help :)

Comment: @tdelaney Yes, I was assuming they tested the script in their home directory, and that they expected it to run the same from systemd. This is likely the most common mistake when using systemd.

Comment: @Barmar what would be a way to test the script as if it was running from systemd? Also, is it equivalent to add a "WorkingDirectory=" instruction in the service to indicate the full path to the subprocess or is one of the solutions better than other for any reason? thank you very much again for your answers

Comment: Use `cd /` before running your script.

Comment: ah ok, of couse, thanks